# Using Return-path when sending mail through SMTP using PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, email-headers, return-path

Is there a way to set the Return-path when sending mail through **authenticated** SMTP using PHP?
I want bounce mails to be caught by another e-mail address than the "from" address.

I know that there is a way to do this with the "normal" PHP mail() function (by setting the "-f" flag in the 5th parameter), but I have no clue how to manage this with SMTP.

Also tried PEAR's Mail-package, but setting Return-path in the headers didn't do the job.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by SMTP; which library/function do you have in mind?

Comment: the return path is usually set by the MTA based on your envelope sender address, eg in SMTP:  MAIL FROM: <bla@example.com>

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_address : [...]When the e-mail is put in the recipient's mailbox, a new mail header is created with the name "Return-Path:" containing the address on the MAIL FROM command. [...]

Comment: Thanks @Gryphius, I understand. But what I actually want to achieve is that the Return-Path is _different_ from the email address set in MAIL FROM, while sending mail using authenticated SMTP in PHP... is there a way to do that?

Comment: no, since the Return path is by definition the address specified in MAIL-FROM and its usually set by the RECEIVING MTA there is no way to change this. I'm starting to think you are trying to solve the wrong problem. why would you want to have an return-path header different from the envelope sender address? Are you sure you are not confusing the MAIL FROM/Envelope sender address with the "From:" header?

Comment: What exactly is your goal, rerouting bounces or changing the address when someone presses the "reply" button? In that case you might want to set the "Reply-To" header, not "Return-Path"

Comment: Hi, did you solved this issue? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Set the fourth `mail()`-parameter (`additional_headers`) to `"Return-path:mybouncereceiver@example.com"`.

Example:

```
$to     = "to@example.com";
$from       = "from@example.com";
$bounce     = "mybouncereceiver@example.com";
$subj       = "mysubject";
$message    = "blah";

$headers    = "From:$from\r\nReturn-path:$bounce"

mail($to, $subj, $message, $headers);
```

You can see that you separate multiple `additional_headers` with `\r\n` (newlines).

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks, but this is the mail()-function, which does not make use of SMTP for sending mails. I'm looking for a way to set the Return-path when sending mails through SMTP.

Comment: @neoMagic You need to be more specific. All mail is sent through SMTP at some layer, but perhaps you mean sent using another function/library?

Comment: I mean sending mail using PHP through **authenticated SMTP**, for example by using the PEAR Mail-package.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do.

You need to set 'Return-Path' in the Headers to the email you want to use as your bounce email. This worked for me.

For example :

```
$headers['From']    = 'richard@example.com';
$headers['To']      = 'joe@example.com';
$headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';
$headers['Return-Path'] = 'bounce@example.com';
```